# getElementsByTagName not working

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am using NODE JS module with which I am creating a HTTP server. Server's response is a page containing JavaScript which embed a webpage in `<iframe>` and within this `<iframe>` I am accessing its elements data with `getElementsByTagName`.

Here is response code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function test() {
        document.body.innerHTML='<iframe id="ifool" src="file:///C:/Users/Naman/Desktop/rew.htm" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-forms allow-scripts"> </iframe>';
        var c;                 
        window.setInterval(function(){
        c=document.getElementById("ifool").contentWindow.location.href; 
        window.history.pushstate(0,0,c);  
        },100);
        window.setInterval(function () {
        var x = document.getElementById("ifool");
        var y = (x.contentWindow || x.contentDocument);
        if (y.document) y = y.document;
        try {
            var a = y.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
            var b = y.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].value;
        } catch (err) {
            txt = "There was an error on this page.\n\n";
            txt += "Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n";
            txt += "Click OK to continue.\n\n";
            alert(txt);
        }
        }, 2000);
</script>
</head>
<body onload= 'test()'>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting error here as "Object [object global] do not have method 'getElementsByTagName'". I am using Chrome with this but I also tried Firefox.

In inspect element console I also getting following errors-

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<History> has no method 'pushstate' localhost: Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL file:///C:/Users/Naman/Desktop/rew.htm from frame with URL http://localhost:8080/. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

Comment: Could you `console.log(x)` and `console.log(y)` for us and add the results to your question?

Comment: I think you are trying to do this `var a = x.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;` instead of mentioning `y` there.

Comment: In my opnion, y = null or undefined... What's browser do you use ?

Comment: what is the `ifool` element

Comment: can you also share teh html including the iframe

Comment: I assume that `y` gets the value of `x.contentWindow` and it doesn't contain a `document`. That is why you got that particular error.

Answer (score 1):

The first error is caused by this line:

```
window.history.pushstate(0,0,c);
```

The correct code is:

```
window.history.pushState(0,0,c);
```

Note the uppercase `S`.

As for the other error, you cannot access iframes and other "restricted" features such as AJAX when viewing the file locally. You must upload it to a server (or start a server on your local machine) in order to use these features.

Comment: If I use some URL instead of local file still it is giving me same error.

Comment: That's because "some URL" is not from the same origin as your file.